# React hot module replacement alternative - Rollup, Gulp and Browsersync

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gulp, browser-sync, rollup

**I am building a React app which has several stages of user interaction to navigate. Working on a stage which is later in the process requires a lot of interaction to get back to the same point when the page is reloaded for changes to the JS.**

Webpack supports HMR which only replaces the modified React component, meaning the entire app doesn't have to be reloaded for each change, seemingly Rollup doesn't support this behaviour.

---

What are the alternatives for Rollup to make the process of developing React apps quicker? I can't go through the entire process of manually entering input data each time to reach the same point in the user journey.

---

I am currently using Rollup to bundle ES6 style imports, pass them to Babel the output of which is served using Browsersync. This is all handled through Gulp.

**Gulp config:**

```
const babelConfig = {
    exclude: 'node_modules/**',
    "presets": [['es2015', { modules: false }], 'react'],
    "plugins": ["external-helpers", "transform-remove-strict-mode", "transform-object-rest-spread"],
    babelrc: false
};

const rollupJS = (inputFile, options) => {
    let notifier = require('node-notifier');

    return () => {
        return plugins.rollupStream({
            entry: options.basePath + inputFile,
            format: options.format,
            sourceMap: options.sourceMap,
            plugins: [
                plugins.rollupPluginBabel(babelConfig),
                plugins.rollupPluginReplace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('dev') }), //production
                plugins.rollupPluginCommonjs({
                    namedExports: {
                        'node_modules/react/index.js': ['Children', 'Component', 'PropTypes', 'createElement'],
                        'node_modules/react-dom/index.js': ['findDOMNode']
                    }
                }),
                plugins.rollupPluginNodeResolve({ jsnext: true, main: true })
            ]
        })
            .pipe(plugins.vinylSourceStream(inputFile, options.basePath))
            .pipe(plugins.vinylBuffer())
            .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({ loadMaps: true }))
            .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('.'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.tmp + '/script/'))
            .pipe(plugins.browserSync.stream());
    };
}

gulp.task('js', rollupJS('app.js', {
    basePath: paths.dev + '/script/',
    sourceMap: true,
    format: 'iife'
}));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only current solution to this problem is to switch over and use Webpack for at least the development side of things so that I could use HMR.

I kept my instance of Rollup to compile the JS for production as it seems to give better returns on filesize and efficiency.

There is currently no foreseeable alternative for HMR in Rollup. This is the only solution.

Comment: It hasn't occurred to me that this dual setup is also possible, good job and thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using Nollup? (https://github.com/PepsRyuu/nollup)

Comment: I use Parcel now, infinitely better than webpack or rollup.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this safe. Using a different bundling tool with a different configuration can result in your production bundle working differently than your development bundle.

Comment: This is a good risk to identify, although in practice there is usually little harm in this approach. Definitely better to use one method for both dev and prod though.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Nollup](https://github.com/PepsRyuu/nollup)?

From the [CLI docs](https://github.com/PepsRyuu/nollup/blob/master/docs/cli.md):

> You're probably already using `rollup -c` in your `package.json` `scripts` section. Nollup functions the same way, you can use `nollup -c` to start a web server that reads your `rollup.config.js` file.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nollup -c"
}
```